# Payment intent doesn't create properly for 'Standard' connected account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm [creating a payment intent as per the Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges#collecting-fees):

```rb
payment_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create({
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  amount: '1000',
  currency: 'aud',
  application_fee_amount: '10', 
}, stripe_account: 'pi_1IwLlIJuxAkCMV')
```

When `stripe_account` is an **Express** account, the payment intent gets created and appears in the dashboard as expected.

But when `stripe_account` is a **Standard** account, the payment intent appears to be created and is visible in the console, but the payment intent is **not** visible in the stripe dashboard, and nor can it be retrieved with `Stripe::PaymentIntent.retrieve(id)`:

```rb
Stripe::PaymentIntent.retrieve(payment_intent.id)
Stripe::InvalidRequestError: No such payment_intent: 'pi_1IwLlIJuxAkCMV'
from stripe-5.26.0/lib/stripe/stripe_client.rb:592:in `handle_error_response'
```

#### Question

Why does creating a payment intent work for **express** connected accounts but not **standard** connected accounts?

Answer (score 0):

In your initial snippet, you likely meant to include an account id like `acct_123` in the optional `stripeAccount` header ([ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/connected_accounts?lang=ruby)). That optional parameter also should be within an `{}` object/hash, though that appears to not be used in the example you linked.

Authenticating as one of your connected accounts like this creates the payment intent as a [direct charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges#types) on the connected account itself (as described eslewhere on the doc you linked).

After creating a direct charge like this, you need to include that same `stripeAccount` header to authenticate during the retrieval:

```
Stripe::PaymentIntent.retrieve(payment_intent.id, { stripeAccount: 'acc'})
```

**Edit to add**: Confirming this `curl` example works as expected:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents \
  -u sk_test_123: \
  --header 'Stripe-Account: acct_123' \
  --data amount=10000 \
  --data currency=usd \
  --data confirm=true \
  --data payment_method=pm_card_visa \
  --data application_fee_amount=500
```

Creates `pi_456`, then:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_456 \
  -u sk_test_123: \
  --header 'Stripe-Account: acct_123' \
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion (previously in javascript, but just now in ruby). It doesn't work, and gives the exact error message as in the question. I think the problem is that the payment_intent doesn't get stored correctly on Stripe's end. It *looks* like it got created, because the payment intent info appears in the console, but it just fails to appear in the dashboard and isn't anywhere to be found when trying to access with methods like `Stripe::PaymentIntent.retrieve()`

Comment: If you try the same thing, and go to your dashboard, do you see a new payment intent there? I am doing what the docs say, so it's very difficult to understand why it wouldn't work, unless the docs are wrong/incomplete, in which case it should not only fail for me, but for everyone attempting the same thing (to create a payment intent for a Standard account with direct  charges.

Comment: Which dashboard are you looking at, your platform or the connected account? I wouldn't expect to see it under the platform account if created as a direct charge.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the additional help. I haven't tried just yet, but will soon and update with my findings. Thanks again, incredibly appreciative!

Comment: I haven't completely worked things out yet (webhook still not working). But your comment about which dashboard to look at made a huge difference. These payment intents were not only being created, but the subsequent payments were even succeeding. I still haven't gotten it working fully yet, but will keep updating so I don't forget what I did. This could save someone else one day.

Comment: I think I know why the webhook isn't working as it does for express. I need to figure which event(s) to have the webhook send. For Express it's the `payment_intent.succeeded` event. I'm going to take some guesses as to what it should be for Standard connected accounts and report back.

Comment: You never mentioned a webhook so I'm not sure how that fits in here.